# Gem not available in self executing ruby file

Tags: ruby, console, listen

I have written myself a simple Ruby script that requires the Listen Gem. Running it in the console like this works perfectly.

```
$ ruby script.rb ARGS
```

I was always passing the PWD as a argument. I got annoyed of that so I wanted to make the script executable across my linux. So I added the following line to the beginning of my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "listen"
...
```

When I now use it as a self executing file, it runs into an error.

```
$ ./script.rb
```

Output:

```
./listen.rb:55: uninitialized constant Listen (NameError)
    from ./script.rb:3:in `require'
    from ./script.rb:3
```

Do you have any suggestions what the cause of this problem could be? I have one guess: `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` calls a different ruby env that `$ ruby` actually is. But how can I find that out? (I am using rbenv to manage my rubys)

Comment: How about `/usr/bin/env ruby -v` This will tell you which version of ruby is used by default. Also, `where ruby` will list all the known ruby binaries.

Comment: Ok, that was a good hint: actually it is `whereis ruby` ;)
Anyways, it gives me multiple paths

`$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/lib/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby1.8 /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz`

and 
`$ /usr/bin/env ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]`
That does not help me alot

Comment: So you have multiple rubies, and one of them is 1.9.3. What does `/usr/bin/ruby -v` give you? Also what about `/usr/bin/env echo $PATH`

Comment: Out of a sudden, it now works the way I expected it. I am using `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` now. Thanks for your help anyways!